# ExtJS 4 and grid selected row

Tags: extjs, grid

I have displayed grid with data from store, just fiev rows with data - simple. When I move mouse over this grid I see highlited row in place where mouse cursor is placed.
I can't stpo this efect. I want to have "clear" grid and no reaction on mouse. Be so kind to prompt me how can I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trackOver: false`.

In your grid add:

```
viewConfig: {
  trackOver: false
}
```